# Wanted to know when to use a do while loop compared to while (example inside)

Tags: c, loops

So I'm working on a square root calculator and I don't know if a while loop is better suited compared to a do while loop.

```
    double x, y = 1.0, newY, squareRoot;
    bool end = true;

    printf("Enter a positve number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    //So here is the loop so which loop would be more effective and why?
    do{
        newY = x / y;
        squareRoot = (newY + y) / 2.0;

        if (fabs(y - newY) < 0.00001)
            end = false;
        else
            y = squareRoot;
    } while (end != false);

    printf("The square root is %.5f\n", y);
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, the logic of `end` seems reversed. You loop while `end` is *true*. It would make more sense to loop while `end` is *false*.

Comment: As for your question, in many cases it's totally subjective which loop one uses. You could use a `while-do` loop, or a `do-while` loop (like you do now) or even a `for` loop if you wanted to. Which one is "best"? I don't know, what you have looks pretty good to me even though I *personally* probably would use a "normal" `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating over a known range of things, use a `for` loop. If you are iterating and are not sure how many things you have, but know when to stop, use a `while` loop.

In your example, a while loop is a good choice, because you know you'll do some number of iterations (with `do...while`, at least one), and you know what the termination condition is: `fabs(y - newY) < 0.00001`.

As a side note, this code assumes you will for sure always converge. If you were not absolutely sure, you'd want to add a iteration count, increment it inside the loop, and make the end-the-loop condition check it as well:  `while( fabs(y - newY) >= 0.00001 && iterations < SOME_LIMIT)`. And of course that condition could be the `while` condition; you don't have to have the `end` boolean to stop the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

`do-while` is an exit control loop and `while` is an entry control loop.

There are cases where you want to execute the statement inside the loop at least once. For e.g. taking input from a user and if the input is invalid then ask the user for valid input otherwise exit loop. `do-while` loop is more suitable in such kind of scenario.

On the other hand, in `while` loop condition is checked before entering into the loop. So if the condition is false for the first time, the statements inside while loop will not execute.

There could be many complex problems where the number of iterations depend upon a certain condition and can't be predicted beforehand, while loop is preferable in those situations.For e.g. reading a file, you don't know how big the file is but you know at some time you will hit end-of-file.

Similarly, in your case, you know the loop termination condition -

```
        if (fabs(y - newY) < 0.00001)
              end = false;
```

but you don't know how many iterations are required beforehand. Also, there are scenarios where you don't need to execute any statement of the loop body, like if the user gives input `1`.

So, `while` loop is more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `do-while` when the break condition may be true on first evaluation and you still want to execute the body of the loop at least once. E.g.

```
bool temp = false;

while (temp == true)
{
    printf("Hello from the while!\n");
}

do {
    printf("Hello from the do!\n");
} while (temp == true);
```

The `do-while` in this case will always execute the body of its scope **at least once**, where as the `while` loop will always evaluate its conditional **before** running the code contained in its body.

Output of program:

```
Hello from the do!
```